# Why is the textbox for posting tweets at the bottom of twitter's new Android UI?

Tags: input, chat

Inspired by this question [here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/51974/why-is-the-input-field-always-at-the-bottom-of-a-chat-window).

I recently updated my twitter app and as I was scrolling up through my feed, I wanted to post something.  After about 30 straight seconds of scanning the top of the screen for some way to post a tweet, I found that this feature had been moved to the bottom of the screen.

From the previously referenced post, this breaks the generally accepted logic there.  Chat windows have their input on the bottom because we read them top down.  Twitter, however, reads bottom up.  From this logic, wouldn't it make more sense for the input to be at the top?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't work for Twitter, and don't know their decision-making process but here are some guesses;

**Usability**

The bottom of the screen is easier to reach with your thumbs.

**Common pattern**

The Default pattern for entering a message on a mobile phone is on the bottom of the screen.

*Having said that, not everything [...]* makes is gold. For example, the pattern that shows/hides the input field on scroll is incredibly counter-intuitive.*

* insert any company's name here

Comment: The input field at the bottom and the bar at the top (just below the blue toolbar) disappear when scrolling to increase the viewport for better reading. Chrome for mobile does the same with the url bar and jQuery plugins that help with that animation have been popping up more frequently recently. It's in the first stages of becoming a convention. But Twitter does a poor job at it, it is counter intuitive as you said. And placing the input at the bottom causes me to press it accidentally multiple times already.

Comment: Not all conventions are good. We should consider themselves the same as, for example, the gravity theory: just a theory. Never, ever stop questioning.

Comment: It's funny we make the comment about hiding the input field, because not even a few minutes ago I was scrolling down to look at old tweets, decided I wanted to post something and thought "where the heck did my input go now?!"

Answer (score 1):

Consistency

Placing the textbox at bottom for either new tweet or reply ( of which the context is above it). In this manner the layour remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

A second logic could be that they placed it at the bottom of the screen because of the new chat function they included. That does read top to bottom and placing the input at the bottom on all screens creates consistency.

Comment: Funny thing is, "chatting" isn't even a new feature.  They just had it in such a nonsense place that nobody knew it existed.

Comment: @RhinoFeeder I didn't even knew that!